# Need Help Optimizing MySQL Query - OR statement in Join causing LONG query time

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have this query being ran on data that is taking the upward of 60-80 seconds. One change in the query drops it under 250ms, but this change causes data to be excluded that's needed.

Here's a SQL Dump (too big for sqlfiddle) of the basic data I'm working with for the query in question: http://pastebin.com/W8w1KFba

NOTE: I added "SQL_NO_CACHE" for testing purposes, and I know some column names have typos but these column names are just for testing purposes and schema in dump was build based on real data but excludes real column names and data.

## Slow Query

#### Query

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
 `Table1`.`recordID`
FROM
  `Table1`
  LEFT JOIN `Table2` ON `Table1`.`recordID`=`Table2`.`table1RecordID`
  LEFT JOIN `Table3` ON `Table2`.`tabel3RecordID`=`Table3`.`recordID` OR `Table3`.`table1RecordID`=`Table1`.`recordID`
WHERE
  (`Table3`.`status` = '3' OR `Table3`.`status` = '4')  AND
  (`Table1`.`groupName` = 'Sample Name')
GROUP BY `Table2`.`tabel3RecordID` ASC, `Table1`.`recordID` ASC;
```

#### Explain

```
+----+-------------+--------+------+--------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type |             possible_key             |     key      | key_len |          ref           | rows  |                          Extras                           |
+----+-------------+--------+------+--------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table1 | ref  | PRIMARY,groupName                    | groupName    | 768     | const                  |    77 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table2 | ref  | fk_packageID                         | fk_packageID | 5       | testDb.Table1.recordID |    88 |                                                           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table3 | ALL  | PRIMARY,fk_packageID,regStatus,pkgID | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                   | 11326 | Using where; Using join buffer                            |
+----+-------------+--------+------+--------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

## Fast (modified slow query) Query

#### Query

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
 `Table1`.`recordID`
FROM
  `Table1`
  LEFT JOIN `Table2` ON `Table1`.`recordID`=`Table2`.`table1RecordID`
  LEFT JOIN `Table3` ON `Table2`.`tabel3RecordID`=`Table3`.`recordID`
WHERE
  (`Table3`.`status` = '3' OR `Table3`.`status` = '4')  AND
  (`Table1`.`groupName` = 'Sample Name')
GROUP BY `Table2`.`tabel3RecordID` ASC, `Table1`.`recordID` ASC;
```

#### Difference

Removed

```
OR `Table3`.`table1RecordID`=`Table1`.`recordID`
```

From line 6

#### Explain

```
+----+-------------+--------+--------+--------------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  |  type  |          possible_key          |     key      | key_len |             ref              | rows |                          Extras                           |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+--------------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table1 | ref    | PRIMARY,groupName              | groupName    |     768 | const                        |   77 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table2 | ref    | fk_registrationID,fk_packageID | fk_packageID |       5 | testDb.Table1.recordID       |   88 | Using where                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table3 | eq_ref | PRIMARY,regStatus              | PRIMARY      |       4 | testDb.Table2.tabel3RecordID |    1 | Using where                                               |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+--------------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

The reason the faster query can't be used is because there can be a case where Table3 contains data a ID in table1RecordID to match to Table1's recordID so I want it include with the data from Table2. So I want data from Table3 where Table2 has a matching ID as well as Table3 data where Table1 ID matches a the column in Table3. This slows the query down massively when I use the OR in the ON clause to get that data included. I see the issue is it creates a temporary table and also copies it to filesystem (filesort).

I'd greatly appreciate any feedback on how I can achieve the data I need and fix the slow query time.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: table3 is not joined to table1 - no wonder it's slow!

Comment: add index on tabl3.recordID seperate these into two queries then use union instead of an OR in JOIN clause 2 fast queries are better than 1 complex slow

Comment: @suspectus How would I use another join but still be able to group all the data down like it does now?

Comment: @SamD I thought a UNION might be the trick but I was having trouble writing that. Any assistant in writing that change? Thanks.

Comment: Is it ever the case that table3 will join *both* ways (resulting in the same row joining twice - once for each join method)

Comment: ... and if table3 *can* join both ways, do you want one in preference to the other? If so, which?

Comment: @Bohemian Everything is grouped down to Table2.tabel3RecordID and Table1.recordID so wouldn't those duplicates be combined to one either way? As for the preference, I need data as it does now where it comes from both joins if there was two, so two become one. Maybe a IF clause on the select for the column could decide which join has the data but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing two joins to the table and separate comparisons for each one.  I think this is the logic:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `Table1`.`recordID`
FROM `Table1`
      LEFT JOIN `Table2` ON `Table1`.`recordID`=`Table2`.`table1RecordID`
      LEFT JOIN `Table3` ON `Table2`.`tabel3RecordID`=`Table3`.`recordID`
      LEFT JOIN `Table3` t3 on t3.`table1RecordID`=`Table1`.`recordID`
WHERE (`Table3`.`status` in ('3', '4') or t3.status in ('3', '4'))  AND
      (`Table1`.`groupName` = 'Sample Name')
GROUP BY `Table2`.`tabel3RecordID` ASC, `Table1`.`recordID` ASC;
```

Comment: This is fast and works, but when I want to select a column from Table3 it wouldn't work out with two separate joins. I know there's no data attached in the example but for examples sake say there's another column that stores a string value that I want to display, with two joins the some data will be in `Table3` and some data will be in the alias `t3` of `Table3`.

Comment: @MasterEthan . . . You would just use `coalesce(table3.colx, t3.colx)` to get the value from one of the tables.

Comment: @GordanLinoff Forgot about that. Let me throw another one at you, what happens when I need to join more tables ON a column from Table3?

Comment: @MasterEthan . . . You need to include the condition on `t3` as well.

Comment: That's what I thought. Hate how more complex it's this is making the query. Wondering if it might be better to do away with Table3.table1RecordID and make it store all associated data using Table2, which will require lots of changes and migration of lots of existing data.

Comment: What if I need to do a inner join at the end to weed out records with no information in the inner join table? I'm no expert in complex queries so I wasn't able to figure out using your query adding a inner join to take out the Table3 records that don't have a record in the Table4 (not in query).